# Is "implicit" a suitable adjective for both "implied" and "inferred" properties?

Tags: terminology, programming

I'm working on some software programming documents where certain types can be *inferred* from the code*. I have this tendency to then called these *inferred* types the *implicit* type. This makes sense because it's a contrast to an *explicit* type.

What bothers me is that the word *implicit* appears to have *imply* as its root. Knowing these types are *inferred* and not *implied* makes it odd to use the word *implicit*. It might however just be the history of the word and thus no longer relevant.

Is it okay to call these *inferred* types an *implicit* type?

**In non-programming terms: I have a document which describes an object. Some of the properties of the object are not actually written down, but can be inferred from the other listed properties.*

Comment: Can they not be inferred **because** they are implied?

Comment: @AndrewLeach, I suppose they could.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to google:

implicit adjective

1. suggested though not directly expressed.

*"comments seen as implicit criticism of the policies"*

1. always to be found in; essentially connected with.

*"the values implicit in the school ethos"*

Looking at the above two definitions, implicit can be used as the qualities are 'indirectly' expressed and hence would have to be inferred. Also, these are qualities, as per my understanding, though not obvious, are an integral part of the code, hence implied.

Comment: Is it fair to say that the "code implies the implicit types" and the compiler "infers the implicit types"?

Comment: If you are asking for your clarity, then yes.

Comment: Please read the second '1.' as '2.'. It simply is not reflecting in the final text!

Answer (score 0):

A speaker or writer can **imply** something ,and the listener or reader can **infer** it .
imply means suggest that something is true without saying or showing it directly .
infer means to form an opinion that is probably true because of other information that you already know .

So by these definitions implicit can not be used.

Comment: The difference between these words is only significant when the **actor** is important. In this case, the **results** of the action are the focus (i.e. the actor doesn't matter), so the words are interchangeable. The properties can be _implied_ or they can be _inferred_, and they are indirectly determined either way.